# Java Properties Save Temporary

Tags: java, properties

I have some issues using properties in java. I have this software that uses properties.
What i want to do is run some code right before the Java software open so i have the following

```
MessageBox.infoBox("Are you ready to be amazed?", "XXX");
String macAdress = MCSystem.getMacAd();
MessageBox.infoBox(macAdress, "This is your MacAddress");
String sAct = config.getProperty("user.activationkey");
MessageBox.infoBox("You have no Activation or invalid Key","first ACT");
if(sAct != null)
{
    MessageBox.infoBox(sAct,"second ACT");        
}
else
{
    String retAct = MessageBox.messageDialog("Please Enter Your Activation Key : ");
    MessageBox.infoBox(retAct, "third ACT");
    config.setProperty("user.activationkey", retAct);
    String testin = config.getProperty("user.activationkey");
    MessageBox.infoBox(testin, "fourth ACT");
}
```

As far as this goes everything works fine, outputs are good and right after that the software opens fine.

Now i would like to display the "user.activationkey" inside the software.
I'm trying to do it like below but i see no result. It's empty.

```
   ActivationKey.setText(config.getProperty("user.activationkey"));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
private void init(File configfile) {
    this.configfile = configfile;
    m_propsconfig = new Properties();

    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reading configuration file: {0}", configfile.getAbsolutePath());
}
...
public String getProperty(String sKey) {
    return m_propsconfig.getProperty(sKey);
}
...
public void setProperty(String sKey, String sValue) {
    if (sValue == null) {
        m_propsconfig.remove(sKey);
    } else {
        m_propsconfig.setProperty(sKey, sValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code how you're loading the properties file

Comment: If it helps the `MachineHostname.setText(config.getProperty("machine.hostname"));` loads just fine right above it @Makky

Comment: In your init method you're loading the Properties variable m_propsconfig with the file provided.

Comment: Yes but when using setProperty shouldn't that update it through the m_propsconfig.setProperty ?

Comment: Yes. But if you have property file then simploy load into your Properties and then use *.getProperty().

Comment: Yes but would i be able to change that if i wanted to at the startup of the application?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43048/discussion-between-makky-and-teris-l)